# How to ensure a static member is defined in a Child class

Tags: c#, interface

I have classes that inherit from an abstract class `FlowData`. `FlowData` implements an interface `IFlow`

My problem, I have a factory class that parses a file and returns a list of `IFlow` type objects depending on what kind of `IFlow` objects can be created from the file. I have two different kinds of classes inheriting from `FlowData` and I want to make sure each object contains a static definition for a property `FlowType`. There is scope to add many other classes that inherit from `FlowData`

The factory logic is as follows

1. Find lines in file beginning with FlowType key word
2. Iterate through `IFlowData` classes in `FlowTypes` namespace in class library
3. If `FlowDataClass.FlowType ==FlowTypeKeyWord` create a `IFlowData` object of the class

This logic relies on each class that inherits from `FlowData` to contain its own unique definition of `FlowType`. Interfaces do not support static members and I can't override a static member in the child class. Is there a clean way to ensure each child class

1. Contains the property `Flowtype`
2. Can implement a unique value for it.

At the moment I am achieving this by defining an interface `IFlowType` and implementing this in my classes that inherit from `FlowData`. My factory class creates a `FlowDataClass` object and checks its `FlowType`. I am just wondering if there is a way to do this without instantiating a `FlowDataClass` object
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered creating / using an [Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/attributes), that you can apply to each implementation to specify the `FlowType`? This by itself would not ensure uniqueness though, but you could check for uniqueness when getting / loading all the types and their applied attributes (and just make sure there is only 1 distinct `Type` for each `FlowType`, and otherwise throw an exception).

Comment: You posted an edit after it was closed. If you beleieve that you have a question that is not addressed by any of the duplicates then be very specific about that part, and state why the duplicates are different.

Comment: I have not used attributes before but this looks like it will solve my problem and give me something new to play around with. Thank you very much :D